# How to create a graph in PHP with quickcharts

Tags: php, html, quickchart

I have a dataset as follows,

```
Timestamp      Value    Importance
5/22/2022 4:19  3245    0.0234
5/22/2022 4:09  3246    0.0214
5/22/2022 4:09  3247    0.1234
5/22/2022 3:59  3248    0.0534
5/22/2022 3:59  3249    0.1234
5/22/2022 3:49  3250    0.0244
5/22/2022 3:49  3251    0.4234
5/22/2022 3:39  3252    0.0534
5/22/2022 3:39  3253    0.0234
5/22/2022 3:29  3254    0.4234
5/22/2022 3:29  3255    0.8234
5/22/2022 3:19  3256    0.1234
5/22/2022 3:19  3257    0.0534
5/22/2022 3:09  3258    0.0334
5/22/2022 3:09  3259    0.0234
5/22/2022 2:59  3260    0.0234
```

I need to show this in a line graph in my php file but I need to highlight point radius according to their importance value, further I need to neglect highlighting all the points which are less than 0.2. So I have searched and found below configuration class from https://quickchart.io/documentation/ but I could not achieve what I need exactly. This will highlight different datasets but not some points only in same dataset.

```
{
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'dataset - big points',
        data: [-15, -80, 79, -11, -5, 33, -57],
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        fill: false,
        borderDash: [5, 5],
        pointRadius: 15,
        pointHoverRadius: 10,
      },
      {
        label: 'dataset - individual point sizes',
        data: [-86, 59, -70, -40, 40, 33, 16],
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        fill: false,
        borderDash: [5, 5],
        pointRadius: [2, 4, 6, 18, 0, 12, 20],
      },
      {
        label: 'dataset - large pointHoverRadius',
        data: [59, -65, -33, 0, -79, 95, -53],
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        fill: false,
        pointHoverRadius: 30,
      },
      {
        label: 'dataset - large pointHitRadius',
        data: [73, 83, -19, 74, 16, -12, 8],
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
        fill: false,
        pointHitRadius: 20,
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Different point sizes',
    },
  },
}
```

Can someone show me how to use above example with my dataset to achieve what I Need?

Answer (score 0):

With [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/charts/line.html?h=pointradius), you can use `pointRadius` as a *scriptable option*.

For example, you can set `pointRadius` dynamically based on the value:

```js
        pointRadius: function (context) {
          const index = context.dataIndex;
          const value = context.dataset.data[index];
          if (value < 0.2) {
            return 0;
          }
          if (value > 0.5) {
            return 20;
          }
          return 10;
        }
```

[Link to example in the QuickChart chart editor](https://quickchart.io/sandbox/#%7B%22chart%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20type%3A%20%27line%27%2C%5Cn%20%20data%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20%5B%27January%27%2C%20%27February%27%2C%20%27March%27%2C%20%27April%27%2C%20%27May%27%2C%20%27June%27%2C%20%27July%27%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20datasets%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B0.4%2C%200.5%2C%200.25%2C%200%2C%200.15%2C%201.0%2C%200.5%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fill%3A%20false%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pointRadius%3A%20function%20(context)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20index%20%3D%20context.dataIndex%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20value%20%3D%20context.dataset.data%5Bindex%5D%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(value%20%3C%200.2)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(value%20%3E%200.5)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%2020%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%2010%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20options%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20legend%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20false%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20true%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%27Dynamic%20point%20sizes%27%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22width%22%3A500%2C%22height%22%3A300%2C%22version%22%3A%222%22%2C%22backgroundColor%22%3A%22%23fff%22%7D)

In your case, use scriptable `pointRadius` to implement logic that returns a point size based on the value (e.g., by looking it up in a table of `importance`).